# Invocar métodos subclase desde la superclase en Java

Tags: java

Pongamos que tenemos una estructura de clases A, B, C relacionadas por Herencia, y queremos que la clase A termine englobando la totalidad de toda la estructura de herencia.

Clases:

```
public class A 
{
    private String a;
    
    public A(String a) { this.a = a; }
    
    public void setA(String a) { this.a = a; }
    public String getA() { return a; }   
}

public class B extends A
{
    private String b;
    
    public B(String a, String b)
    {
        super(a);
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    public void setB(String b) { this.b = b; }
    public String getB() { return "Diffuse"; }
}

public class C extends B
{
    private String c;
    
    public C(String a, String b, String c)
    {
        super(a, b);
        this.c = c;
    }
    
    public void setC(String c) { this.c = c; }
    public String getC() { return c; }   
}

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<A> arrayA = new ArrayList<>();
        
        C c1 = new C("a1", "b1", "c1");
        
        c1.getA();
        c1.getB();
        c1.getC();
        
        arrayA.add(c1);
        
        arrayA.get(0).getA();
        arrayA.get(0).setA("arrayA");  
    }
}
```

Desde arrayA (la clase Padre) se pierde el acceso a los métodos de las clases Hijo (B, C), y sólo tenemos acceso a los métodos de la propia clase A.

¿Como puedo mantener toda la jerarquía de clases almacenada en la clase padre sin perder el acceso a los métodos de las clases hijo?.

He buscado en Google y diferentes foros pero no termino de dar con la solución.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En el código no aparece pero las clases tienen un constructor sin parámetros.

Comment: Si tenes una nueva pregunta, hacela.. no cambies tu pregunta porque no se entiende cual fue la respuesta y cual es la pregunta si no... entiendo que quieras un seguimiento, pero si cambias la pregunta, no se entiende la respuesta...

Answer (score 1):

El propósito de la herencia es evitar la duplicación de código y permite contar con todo lo que la super-clase tiene para ofrecer.

No necesitas *acceder a las cosas de tu sub-clase desde tu super-clase*. Puedes castearlo a su tipo original y tendrás acceso a todos sus métodos.

```
C c2 = (C)arrayA.get(0);
c2.setC("Hola");
```

Si no sabes de antemano de qué tipo es, deberías agregar una función a todas las clases que te permita saberlo. Por ejemplo:

```
class A {
    ...
    public String getType() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    ...
    public String getType() {
        return "B";
    }
}

A a = new B();
b.getType(); // "B"
```

Si eso no te sirve, tal vez debas investigar [Reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html).

Comment: Buscaba algo similar a lo que hace C++, una clase o función determinada tiene como parámetro la clase Padre y puede recibir a cualquiera de sus hijos, ya que un hijo forma parte del padre.  Si he entendido bien tu respuesta, para cada objeto debería comprobar de que clase es mediante un `instanceof`, y posteriormente castearlo al tipo de objeto hijo concreto. Quizá no formule correctamente la pregunta, sinceramente no entiendo el punto negativo que le han dado a la pregunta.

Comment: He editado la pregunta añadiendo lo que he entendido de tú respuesta, por favor, si puedes, échale un vistazo. En las clases he añadido un constructor por defecto sin parámetros.

Comment: @Torkan si pusieras un ejemplo de lo que quieres de C++ podrías obtener una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu respuesta @Mateo el código debería ser algo así en el Main o la clase receptora del ArrayList:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<A> arrayA = new ArrayList<>();
        
        A a1 = new A("a3");
        B b1 = new B("a2", "b2");
        C c1 = new C("a1", "b1", "c1");
        
        c1.getA();
        c1.getB();
        c1.getC();
                
        arrayA.add(c1);
        arrayA.add(b1);
        arrayA.add(a1);
        
        arrayA.get(0).getA();
        arrayA.get(0).setA("arrayA");
          
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        for (A f : arrayA)
        {
            if (f instanceof C)
            {
                c = (C)f; 
                System.out.println("Object C: A: " + c.getA() + " B: " + c.getB() + " C: " + ((C) f).getC());   
            }
            else if (f instanceof B)
            {
                b = (B)f;
                System.out.println("Object B: A: " + f.getA() + " B: " + ((B) f).getB());
            }
            else if (f instanceof A)
            {
                System.out.println("Object A: " + f.getA());
            }
        } 
    }
}
```